# How can I find a hierarchy from a closure table in MYSQL if I have a list of names within the hierarchy?

Tags: mysql, transitive-closure-table

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1495/1

I have a table named "locations":

```
id  name        parent
1   Sweden      0
2   England     0
3   Stockholm   1
4   Vasteras    1
5   Town        3
6   Town        4
7   London      2
8   Town        7
```

And table named "closure":

```
parent  child   depth
1       1       0
1       3       1
1       4       1
1       5       2
1       6       2
2       2       0
2       7       1
2       8       2
3       3       0
3       5       1
4       4       0
4       6       1
5       5       0
6       6       0
7       7       0
7       8       1
8       8       0
```

Now I'd like to convert a hierarchy of names I have on hand into location IDs.

Example: Sweden => Stockholm => Town would yield:

```
id      name        parent
1       Sweden      0
3       Stockholm   1
5       Town        3
```

How could I do this without also returning any of the places named "town",  but where the parents aren't exactly the same?